# Asp.net Mvc 4 with Bootstrap Menu Left not collapse option

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Asp.Net MVC 4, razor and Bootstrap 3, I copied the template "bootstrap" in Layout.cshtml in my project Asp.net MVC the code is the same but collapse menu not function not expand the menu by click in option "Charts", how I can resolve this problem?
this is the code in Layout.cshtml

```
<li>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
   <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
       <li>
          <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
   <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
</li>
```

as you can see in the image only show me the menu in expand but when I click by "Charts" not collapse the menu

[image]

Comment: Your code is written for it not to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my platform. I use mvc5 default web application and bootstrap 3.

The common problem is in the path of the js and css files. After copying the theme make sure you have the right paths ex

```
<script src="~/Content/admin2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

and then run again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by including the proper libraries (JavaScript) not on the view but on the _Layout.cshtml file just before `</body>` tag.